# Strange behavior of EventTrigger (WPF)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, animation

Considering following example (taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger.aspx) sample)

```
<Style TargetType="Rectangle">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
              <DoubleAnimation To="300" Duration="0:0:1.5" 
                AccelerationRatio="0.10" DecelerationRatio="0.25" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Width)" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
              <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1.5" 
                AccelerationRatio="0.10" DecelerationRatio="0.25" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Width)" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

There are 2 animiations, one for MouseEnter event, and another one for Mouse leave event.

Note that In the animation of Mouse Leave event, only Duration is specified. No From/To.By is specified.
The remark section of [DoubleAnimation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation.aspx) specified either of From/To/By must be specified.
My question is how this animation is working? Is it considering original value of rectangle as `To` value for the animation.

Answer (score 1):

its working by transitioning back to the default value.  the table you referred to only specifies behavior when various combinations of from/to/by are used.

each storyboard is independent, so they wont keep track of what the other storyboard has done, so the first one transitions to the width defined, and the second will transition it back to the original value.

Comment: The ending value of the animation. The default value is null. From `DoubleAnimation.To` [MSDN](The ending value of the animation. The default value is null.).
It seems like it is going to original value that was set before first animation (on MouseEnter), But why this is happening, I am not finding any information.

Comment: if you dont specify a To/From/By, the doubleanimation doesnt know what rules its supposed to use to transition from the current property state (canvas.width), so it ends up using whatever the properies default value is.  a rectangle defined to have a width of 50 will transition back to 50 on mouseleave because doubleanimation's To/From/By don't give direction on what other value it should transition to.

Comment: That is my assumption too, but can you provide some reference stating this behavior.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx#animationtypes   this article mentions what the effect is if you specify to/from/by, so it can be implied that it does something else if they aren't specified.       http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970265.aspx   However, you can also specify only a starting value, a destination value, or an offset value. In these cases, the animation obtains the missing target value from the property that is being animated.